# NUXT3 How to display markdown content as html tags?

Tags: vue.js, rest, nuxt.js, directus

I am trying to display my markdown content from REST API to my NUXT3 application. I can get raw data with this

```html
<h2 class="bg-slate-100 p-5 mt-5 border rounded">{{ Services.data.Test[0].Title}}</h2>
<p class="bg-slate-100 p-5 mt-5 border rounded" >{{ Services.data.Test[0].Test_Data}}</p>
```

Using DirectUS -

```html
<script setup>
const { $directus } = useNuxtApp()
const { data: Services } = await useAsyncData('Services', () => {
    return $directus.items('Services').readByQuery()
})
// console.log($directus);
</script>
```

I am getting this without proper P and H tags which I set in my markdown content. Its looking raw text.. I want to make it html format like it should look.
How can I use markdown here ? In NUXT2, we can use markdownit module... but in NUXT3, its not compatible.
I read NUXT content module docs but can not find what I am looking for.

Answer (score 10):

In Nuxt 3 it's possible to use markdownit, i'm use in my application, i will share my files

```
Package.json:
"@types/markdown-it": "^12.2.3",
"markdown-it": "^13.0.1",
"nuxt": "3.1.0",
```

Here is the code snippet from the project:

```
// @/plugins/markdownit.ts
import md from "markdown-it";

export default defineNuxtPlugin(() => {
  const renderer = md();
  return {
    provide: {
      mdRenderer: renderer,
    },
  };
});
```

RichText.vue

```
<!-- @/components/strapi_components/blocks/RichText.vue -->
    <script lang="ts" setup>
    const props = defineProps({
      block: {
        type: Object,
        required: true,
      },
    });
    onBeforeMount(() => {
      !["content"].every((propName) => props.block.hasOwnProperty(propName))
        ? console.error(`RichText.vue has not pass the block property validation`)
        : null;
    });
    </script>
    
    <template>
      <div class="container mx-auto grid place-content-center">
        <div
          class="prose-xl border border-gray-300 prose-blue prose-pre:bg-zinc-300 prose-pre:text-gray-800 text-sm m-5 p-5 bg-gray-100 shadow-xl rounded-2xl"
          v-html="$mdRenderer.render(block.content)"
        />
      </div>
    </template>
```

There's no need to register the plugin, nuxt does it for you.v

Comment: Thank you so much. Perfect answer. You saved my day!
v-html="$mdRenderer.render(Services.data.Test[0].Test_Data)"
Also tell me if it is good practice or not ? Or is there any other NUXT3 way ?

Comment: How do you pass options to `markdown-it` then? For instance, I need `html: true` to correctly convert the "em dash"...